# spring boot email authentication failure

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, email

I have a spring boot app that should be sending an email to the customer's email address after a certain action is triggered, I have enabled a two factor authentication in my email, generated an app password and that's what I am using for the project in place of the email password but still getting this error every time
Caused by: jakarta.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.9 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. For more
534-5.7.9 information, go to
534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WebLoginRequired v12-20020a05600c470c00b0040d5f3ef2a2sm1362856wmo.16 - gsmtp.

```
This is how I configured it

application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bankingdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=********
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=elijahukeme22@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=ecxtwyrppomykkkj
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

@Service
public class EmailServiceImplementation implements EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String senderEmail;

    @Override
    public void sendEmailAlert(EmailDetails emailDetails) {
        try {
            SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
            simpleMailMessage.setFrom(senderEmail);
            simpleMailMessage.setTo(emailDetails.getRecipient());
            simpleMailMessage.setText(emailDetails.getMessageBody());
            simpleMailMessage.setSubject(emailDetails.getSubject());

            javaMailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
            System.out.println("Email sent successfully");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public interface EmailService {

    void sendEmailAlert(EmailDetails emailDetails);
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class EmailDetails {
    private String recipient;
    private String messageBody;
    private String subject;
    private String attachment;
}


I don't really know the reasons for that. Here is the full error from the logcat

org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:402)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:317)
    at org.springframework.mail.MailSender.send(MailSender.java:42)
    at com.elijahukeme.bankingdemoproject.service.imple.email.EmailServiceImplementation.sendEmailAlert(EmailServiceImplementation.java:30)
    at com.elijahukeme.bankingdemoproject.service.imple.bank.BankAccountServiceImplementation.createAccount(BankAccountServiceImplementation.java:69)
    at com.elijahukeme.bankingdemoproject.controller.bank.BankAccountController.createAccount(BankAccountController.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: jakarta.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.9 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. For more
534-5.7.9 information, go to
534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WebLoginRequired v12-20020a05600c470c00b0040d5f3ef2a2sm1362856wmo.16 - gsmtp

    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:954)
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:769)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:480)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:399)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: I hope this is not the real password you posted here. If it is, you should immediately change it.

Comment: It's not the real password. Nevertheless I have solved it. The issue was because I just created the email address recently. I used my former email address and it worked fine